# I want to remove the aesthetics legend in my plot using ggmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am relatively new to ggplot2 and ggmap.  I am having trouble with duplicate legends.  The legend that I want remove is created in the 'Fill' section of the code I believe.

```
## Kootenai map
Koot_base = get_map(location = c(-116,49), zoom = 7,
                   maptype = 'roadmap')
KootBase = ggmap(Koot_base)
## Coloring map for data
Fill = stat_bin2d(aes(x = YearPercDat[,2], y = YearPercDat[,1],
       colour = YearPercInd, fill = YearPercInd), size=.9,
       bins = 100, alpha = .5, data = YearPercFort)
## Outlining subbasin
Outline = geom_polygon(aes(x = kootenai.coord[,1], y = kootenai.coord[,2]), 
          data = kootenai.coord, colour = 'black', fill = NA, alpha = 0.4,
          size = 0.75)
## Titles
Axes = labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
Main = ggtitle(paste("Kootenai Subbasin ",year,sep=''))
## Scale
Scale = scale_fill_discrete(name = "Percent of Year Snow Covered",
        labels = c("Greater than 0","0"))

ggmap(Koot_base) + Fill + Outline + Axes + Main + Scale
```

Below is the first 100 rows of my dataset.

```
> dput(Dat2)
structure(list(V1 = c(50.078331, 50.140011, 50.051201, 50.071758, 
50.0923, 50.11282, 50.133331, 50.15382, 50.17429, 50.003502, 
50.024059, 50.044601, 50.065121, 50.085629, 50.106121, 50.126591, 
50.147041, 49.976372, 49.99691, 50.017429, 50.037941, 50.05843, 
50.078899, 50.09935, 50.119781, 50.140202, 50.160599, 50.201351, 
49.94923, 49.969761, 49.990261, 50.01075, 50.031219, 50.05167, 
50.072102, 50.092522, 50.112919, 50.133301, 50.15366, 50.174011, 
50.19434, 50.214649, 49.881031, 49.901569, 49.922089, 49.9426, 
49.963081, 49.983551, 50.004002, 50.024429, 50.044849, 50.06525, 
50.085629, 50.105991, 50.126339, 50.14666, 50.166969, 50.187271, 
49.812832, 49.833389, 49.85392, 49.874439, 49.894939, 49.915428, 
49.935902, 49.956348, 49.97678, 49.997189, 50.01759, 50.037971, 
50.058331, 50.078678, 50.098999, 50.119308, 50.139599, 50.159882, 
49.785751, 49.80629, 49.826801, 49.847301, 49.86779, 49.888248, 
49.908699, 49.929131, 49.949551, 49.96994, 49.990318, 50.010681, 
50.031029, 50.05135, 50.071659, 50.091949, 50.112228, 50.132481, 
49.676418, 49.738129, 49.758659, 49.779179, 49.799679, 49.82016
), V2 = c(-117.192703, -117.066025, -117.160736, -117.118576, 
-117.076355, -117.034103, -116.991791, -116.949432, -116.907043, 
-117.170914, -117.128815, -117.08667, -117.044464, -117.002213, 
-116.95993, -116.917587, -116.875198, -117.139038, -117.096954, 
-117.05481, -117.012619, -116.970383, -116.928116, -116.885773, 
-116.843414, -116.800995, -116.758514, -116.673447, -117.107193, 
-117.065125, -117.022995, -116.98082, -116.938599, -116.896347, 
-116.854019, -116.811661, -116.769257, -116.726807, -116.684296, 
-116.641754, -116.599167, -116.556519, -117.159393, -117.117432, 
-117.075409, -117.03334, -116.991226, -116.949066, -116.906876, 
-116.864609, -116.822311, -116.779968, -116.737579, -116.695145, 
-116.652649, -116.610107, -116.567535, -116.524918, -117.211411, 
-117.16954, -117.127625, -117.085663, -117.043655, -117.001617, 
-116.959503, -116.917374, -116.875168, -116.832947, -116.790649, 
-116.748322, -116.705933, -116.663513, -116.621033, -116.578522, 
-116.53595, -116.493347, -117.179657, -117.137802, -117.095901, 
-117.053955, -117.011963, -116.969925, -116.927841, -116.885712, 
-116.843536, -116.801315, -116.759033, -116.716705, -116.674347, 
-116.631943, -116.589478, -116.546967, -116.504425, -116.461823, 
-117.31485, -117.189743, -117.147949, -117.10611, -117.064224, 
-117.022293), V3 = c(48.3425414364641, 48.3425414364641, 48.3425414364641, 
70.1657458563536, 72.6519337016575, 70.1657458563536, 70.1657458563536, 
0, 24.8618784530387, 70.1657458563536, 46.4088397790055, 37.8453038674033, 
70.1657458563536, 68.232044198895, 58.0110497237569, 0, 24.8618784530387, 
70.1657458563536, 69.6132596685083, 26.2430939226519, 70.1657458563536, 
67.6795580110497, 0, 24.8618784530387, 47.5138121546961, 79.8342541436464, 
79.8342541436464, 75.1381215469613, 61.878453038674, 59.3922651933702, 
32.3204419889503, 59.3922651933702, 59.3922651933702, 0, 24.8618784530387, 
50.5524861878453, 56.9060773480663, 51.9337016574586, 75.1381215469613, 
77.9005524861878, 54.9723756906077, 98.3425414364641, 61.878453038674, 
61.6022099447514, 80.3867403314917, 71.5469613259668, 61.0497237569061, 
48.3425414364641, 0, 0, 25.414364640884, 25.414364640884, 25.414364640884, 
57.182320441989, 45.8563535911602, 46.6850828729282, 46.6850828729282, 
79.8342541436464, 61.6022099447514, 70.1657458563536, 61.6022099447514, 
46.4088397790055, 37.8453038674033, 32.3204419889503, 32.3204419889503, 
58.0110497237569, 0, 24.8618784530387, 58.0110497237569, 56.9060773480663, 
56.9060773480663, 37.292817679558, 79.8342541436464, 58.5635359116022, 
72.9281767955801, 43.9226519337017, 59.9447513812155, 39.5027624309392, 
61.878453038674, 70.1657458563536, 70.1657458563536, 71.5469613259668, 
26.2430939226519, 0, 24.8618784530387, 26.5193370165746, 70.1657458563536, 
70.1657458563536, 43.3701657458564, 57.182320441989, 51.9337016574586, 
72.0994475138122, 53.8674033149171, 72.9281767955801, 27.3480662983425, 
51.1049723756906, 61.878453038674, 61.6022099447514, 72.9281767955801, 
72.3756906077348), V4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output I am getting
[image]

Comment: your example is not reproducible. we don't have access to YearPercDat

Comment: Is there any way I can attach the data?

Comment: run dput(nameofyourdatset) in R; it does not have to be the full dataset, just enough to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, does this work?

Comment: that was the right way, but your header is V1-V4 and V4 is filled with 0.

Comment: Yeah V4 is just an indicator for whether or not V3 is a 0.  A value of 1 for V4  just means that this gridpoint had no snow on it the entire year.  A value of 0 means it had at least some snow.

Comment: but  it your code where YearPercDat[,2] and YearPercDat[,1] are coming from?

Comment: V1 is the first column and they are latitudes and V2 is the second column and then are longitudes V3 is the third column and they are the percent of the year each grid point is covered in snow.  YearPercDat[,2] is just calling V2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to leave out the `colour` argument in your call. For a bin2d, the colour is the outline - no need for an outline when you are already using fill:

```
library(ggmaps)
ggmap(Koot_base) +
   stat_bin2d(data = YearPercDat, aes(x = V2, y = V1, fill = as.factor(V4))) + 
   scale_fill_discrete(name = "Percent of Year Snow Covered", labels = c("Greater than 0","0"))
```

[image]

If for whatever reason you want to keep colour in, you can set the `colour` guide to false:

```
+ guides(colour = FALSE)
```

NB the way you are calling the `aes` by subsetting by columns is not the best. Better to use the names - ie `V4` `V2` etc so any subsetting etc carried out by the plotting functions is carried out correctly.